# How to change color scheme based on selected language

Tags: html, angular, colors

In Angular how can i make a color palette based on selected language. I want it to work like languages in notepad++. I have input where user paste code and place where it is formatted. Everything is working fine i just need tags and text to have color. It should be different if it is HTML, CSS or some other language.

[image]

Comment: Please read the documentation for the Angular Material library.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can define CSS classes and then you can bind value to this class in HTML.

For example:

HTML

```
<div class={{ color }}>
...
</div>
```

TS

```
color: string = "blue"
```

CSS

```
.blue { background-color: blue }
.green { background-color: green}
```

So you can dynamicly change values of the color property in TS.
Hope this helps.